# Create function in Python depending of x which returns a composition of functions depending of x

Tags: python, function, numpy, nested

I want to apply a function `f` to a data `X`, beign `X` a numpy array. The problem is that `f` is a sort of "linear combination" of functions, let's say `f_i`, and each of this functions depends also of another parameter, let's say:

```
param = 1.0  #same param for every f_i call.
def f(x):
    for xi in range(len(x)):
       cummulate sum of f_i(x, xi, param)
    return the result of the loop, which depends of (x)
```

Any help with this? I tried sympy but the `f_i` are not trivial math function, but a combination of them.

Comment: And do the f_i functions change on each i iteration to another function or do they repeat during this for? What about making  a kind of dict with lambda functions:

{"1": lambda x: return x,
 "2": lambda x: return x,
   .... 
}

Comment: @RicardoBurillo the f_i function is always the same, the only change is the "param" parameter.

Comment: I edited the question, it said "len(x)" but it was a range(len(x)). I think people got the idea with no problem.

Comment: where does param come from?

Comment: param comes from outside `f`, is just a float and is the same for each call to `f_i`,  editing that...

Comment: How many `f_i` are there?  How many `param`?  It's unclear what `i` is doing in the iteration.  Is it selected a function, element of `x`, or a `param`.

Comment: I changed `i` to `xi`. There is only one `f_i` defined, but called len(x) times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few approaches here.

First and easiest is to pass in `params` as an argument, which could be an array of extra arguments for each function:

```
def f(x, params):
    for i in len(x):
        # Pass in params[i] to f_i
```

In the case that you need `f` to only accept one argument, you can do the second approach using a [closure](http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html):

```
def f_creator(params):
    def closure(x):
        for i in len(x):
            # Pass in params[i] to f_i
    return closure

f = f_creator(... params for f_is go in here...)
# Use f for any special calculations that you need
```

Finally if these parameters are constant and don't change over the course of your program, you can set them to global constants. This approach isn't recommended because it makes it difficult to test things and makes the code less robust to change.

```
params = ....

def f(x):
    for i in len(x):
        # Calculate f_i using global params
```

Comment: ok, to make things easier, the param is always the same, no array of different params. So, the last approach, inside the correct scope, or the first approach seems clean and useful.

Comment: The first loop is a bit pointless,you can iterate directly over the list.